# Aharonov-Bohm vs de Witt

Tags: history

dewitt claimed in his paper

> Bryce S. DeWitt. Quantum theory without electromagnetic potentials, *Phys. Rev.* **125** no. 6 (1962), pp. 2189-2191, [DOI:    10.1103/PhysRev.125.2189](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.125.2189),

that the discovery of the Aharonov and Bohm that electromagnetic potentials play primary role in quantum mechanical theory is false. Who won? What are the errors in the argument of the losing side in this battle?

Comment: What is the full reference to DeWitt's paper?

Comment: I added the reference to DeWitt's paper in question.

Comment: I think reading these two follow-up papers by Aharonov and Bohm will clarify the issue: http://prola.aps.org/abstract/PR/v125/i6/p2192_1 and http://prola.aps.org/abstract/PR/v130/i4/p1625_1 .

Answer (score 2):

There is no losing side in this battle--- DeWitt is pointing out that you can express the local vector potential in a nonlocal form in terms of the fields everywhere in space. If you know E and B everywhere, you can figure out what A is supposed to be, once you choose a gauge. This is not in contradiction to the statement that the local equations of motion involve only A.

The reason nobody tries to do this anymore is because in nonabelian theories, as in electromagnetism on nontrivial topologies, you can't reconstruct A nonlocally from E and B, you need to know the Wilson loops.

Comment: Just a comment: to reconstruct the potential with the Wilson loop, see this: https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.24.2160